# Why is `.append($(message_element))` only producing `[object Object]` as output?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to show the message from the server in the HTML page, but whenever I write the message, it says `[object Object]`.
The value has been correctly parsed, but the problem seems to be while appending.

```js
let input_message = document.querySelector('#input-message')
let message_body = document.querySelector('.msg_card_body')
let send_message_form = document.getElementById('send-message-form')
let loc = window.location
let wsStart = 'ws://'

if (loc.protocol === 'https') {
  wsStart = 'wss://'
}

let endpoint = wsStart + loc.host + loc.pathname
var socket = new WebSocket(endpoint)

socket.onopen = function(event) {
  console.log('open', event)
  send_message_form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    
    let message = input_message.value
    let data = {
      'message': message,
    }
    
    data = JSON.stringify(data)
    socket.send(data)
  })
}
socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  console.log('message', event)
  // console.log(typeof(event.data))
  
  let data = JSON.parse(event.data)
  
  // console.log(typeof(data))
  
  let message = data['message']
  
  // console.log(message)
  newMessage(message)
}
socket.onerror = function(event) {
  console.log('error', event)
}
socket.onclose = function(event) {
  console.log('closed', event)
}

function newMessage(message) {
  if ($.trim(message) === '') {
    return false;
  }

  let message_element = `
    <div class="d-flex mb-4 replied">
      <div class="msg_cotainer_send">
        ${message}
        <span class="msg_time_send">8:55 AM, Today</span>
      </div>
      <div class="img_cont_msg">
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;">
      </div>
    </div>
  `

  // console.log($(message_element))
  message_body.append($(message_element))
  message_body.animate({
    scrollTop: $(document).height()
  }, 100);
  input_message.value = '';
}
```

It is not adding any style and it’s not passing any given value. It seems it is taking while `message_element` as an object and displaying that.
I tried using `insertAdjecentHTML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re confusing the native DOM API’s [`append`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/append) with jQuery’s [`append`](//api.jquery.com/append).
Mixing the jQuery API with the native DOM API in code is not recommended for this very reason.

`Element.prototype.append` accepts [`Node`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node) objects, or strings as its arguments (0 or more).

`jQuery.fn.append` accepts HTML strings, [`Element`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element) objects, [`Text`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Text) objects, Arrays of Nodes, or jQuery objects as its arguments (0 or more).

You were passing a jQuery object to `Element.prototype.append`.
In the [WebIDL definition of `append`](//dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-parentnode-append), it specifies its arguments to be of the union type `(Node or DOMString)`.
An arbitrary jQuery object cannot be converted to a `Node`, so the only other option is to convert it to a [`DOMString`](//webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#idl-DOMString).
This conversion *is* possible by [mapping an ECMAScript value to a WebIDL `DOMString`](//webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#es-DOMString), which basically calls ECMAScript’s [ToString](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tostring) abstract operation on the object.
The stringification of a jQuery object results in the default `"[object Object]"` string.
Strings are then [converted to the equivalent `Text` nodes](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#converting-nodes-into-a-node) and eventually inserted into the DOM.

Any of these work:

| API | Suggestion | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jQuery | `$(message_body).append(message_element)` | Passing an HTML string to `jQuery.fn.append`. |
| DOM | `message_body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", message_element)` | Passing an HTML string to [`Element`’s `insertAdjacentHTML`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) |